# Get all data, show only relevent data from a return

Tags: sql, loops

I've been tasked to change someone else's code without rewriting the project. I have an sql statement that grabs all data from a customer table. The return gets:

```
Inum - which can have many of the same entries.
Istep - Which is unique but bound to above.
Istage - which is unique and bound to above.
```

It looke like this:

```
10010 - 100 - 999
10010 - 101 - 888
10010 - 102 - 777
10018 - 100 - 999
10018 - 130 - 555
10026 - 300 - 333
```

I want to just get the first Inum of each set so that I get:

```
10010 - 100 - 999
10018 - 100 - 999
10026 - 300 - 333
```

I would then strip off the last part - Istep and allow that to be assigned down the script when an Index change takes place in the all (VB.NET)
I need to keep getting ALL data as it is packaged into a var on the page and is reused based on its current content over and over. I may need to do it in VB, not sure.

Addition (based on first answer):
@eaolson - Thank you for the reply. Gross typos aside...I should have been clearer. The Istep is unique to where we are in the flow in that we can only be one place at a time per item(Inum). But they are all in the db and the way it is pulled they all come back. The same is true for Istage. It is unique to the Step we are in, but all stages and steps up to the current point get pulled. There are no rowguides or unique ID's that I can find. They did most all tables this way and it is tough making some changes. What I want is a single Inum. So the call gets the first Inum 10010, then ignores the rest until it get a chage 10018, then skipps the rest of 10018's until a change 10026, skips the rest until the next 10023, etc. I still neeed ALL * data as he packs it into a var to be pulled from there down the page. I'm stumped. I was thinking to pull it into a datagrid (.NET) and using it for the rest of the calls. But I would rather do it in SQL if possible as I know I will neeed to do this over and over again due to the way this was built. Thanks.

Comment: You want to do it in code or in query?

Comment: Doesn't the answer by @eaolson do what you want and what DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "first value", do you mean "minimum value"? Row order is not necessarily guaranteed in a table.

```
SELECT t1.inum, t1.istep, t1.istage
  FROM mytable t1
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT inum, MIN(istep) as min_istep
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY inum ) t2 ON t2.inum = t1.inum AND t2.min_istep = t1.istep
```

You also say that istep and istage are "unique" but they have repeating values in your example. I assumed that (inum, istep) is your primary key.